# Managing the permissions for my Wiki template

Tags: permissions, 2013

On this MSDN link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx#section1 they talk about permission and permission levels mainly in respect to List and list item. For example which permisoon allow to create a list , which allow to create a list item , approve a list item, etc…

But I am creating a publishing site which contain Enterpirse wiki library, so I do not know how I can map the default permission to my Wiki site, can I for example consider a wiki site as a List and adding wiki articles as adding new list item , Or this will not be valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiki Articles are stored as documents within a document library. A document library is a kind of list, where each item has an associated file. Wherever they refer to "items" in that document it would apply to Wiki articles.